# Progress in Guy's "Unsolved problems in Number Theory"?

Tags: nt.number-theory, open-problems

I often peruse through [Guy's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387208607) whenever I'm not being boggled down by my research. It crossed my mind today if any of these "unsolved problems" have become indeed solved. I thought about doing a literature review to find out, but I realised that posting this question here is a much more a efficient way of finding the current status of these problems. I'm also open to finding out about  any recent breakthroughs concerning said problems.

Comment: This question is way too broad.

Comment: What if the question was reworded as "which open problems from Guy's book have since been solved?", and the post made community wiki?

Comment: @René Why stop there? How about "Which open problems in all the books on number theory have since been solved?".  Are we ready to replicate MathSciNet?

Comment: For that matter, why not just check a citation index for citations to Guy's book?  Gerhard "Shouldn't That Answer The Question?" Paseman, 2015.09.29

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: Why would anyone solving a problem cite Guy's book? -- For most problems it is not the original source, and people might not even know that that book *also* contains the problem they have solved.

Comment: For many people it is the source from which they first learned of the problem.  Also, they might be helpful and tell Guy that it was solved, getting another mention in the next version.   Gerhard "That's The Way I Think" Paseman, 2015.09.29

Comment: The review of (the 3rd edition of) the book at MathSciNet says the book is mentioned in the references of 189 other reviews, and in the body of 13 reviews.

Comment: I'm really unsure as to why this question was marked as too broad. I just want a binary answer (yes/no?) and a bit of exposition on the progress on the current status of a given problem. Guy's book isn't even that big. There's even a lot more to be gained from having this available on MathOverflow.

Comment: @user119264 : A bit of exposition on the progress of *every single* problem in Guy's book sounds like a new edition of Guy's book.  A typical MO question asks for the status of *one* problem that the questioner is interested in.

Comment: @TimothyChow Nowhere did I mention wanting the status of EVERY single problem. It's highly unlikely that even if the entire MO community pulled together that the status of every single problem would even be answered. I don't even understand how you think this could even fill a new book. If a user is familiar with the most RECENT developments about a problem in the book then they can simply say 'I read an interesting paper on it [cite here] blah blah blah'.  This would take at most a paragraph, if so much.

Comment: @user119264 : I recommend that you edit your question to make it clearer what you're asking.  If five people thought it was too broad then that is evidence that the way you phrased your request sounds too broad to a lot of people, and that you should therefore rephrase it.  For example, when you ask about "any" of the unsolved problems, it sounds to many people that you want updates to all of them, and when you refer to "these problems" and "said problems" it also sounds like a reference to the set of all problems in the book.

Comment: @TimothyChow 5 people thinking it is too broad versus the 12 people thinking it should be made a post wiki, not to mention the 11 that upvoted it? I wonder what's the stronger correlation here?

Comment: Do you mean the 12 people who upvoted the comment suggesting that your post be reworded?  I'm one of those 12.  It's really your choice.  You can be argumentative and insist that you're right, or you can reword your question so that it can be reopened and so that you can get your question answered.